# Do cheap iPad Lightning to USB camera adapters work?

Tags: ipad, usb, jailbreak, storage

Do cheap iPad lightning to USB adapters (from websites such as eBay) work or can a get a genuine Apple adapter for a lower price somewhere? I do not want to pay at least $39 AUD for one. My iPad mini is jailbroken and I wish to use one to symlink apps to a USB flash drive because I only have a 16GB model and I'm always trying to find things to delete to free up space. Is it worth the money for an Apple branded adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the adapters from apple have such a high price is because the product have a chip inside that will make sure the product keeps working. Cheaper product often don't have such a chip. It is possible that those products work, but they can stop working at a random time.

There are products from other companies that are also supported by apple because they pay a licence to develop such products.

Every product that has the "made for iPod, iPad and iPhone" logo on it's cover are supported by apple.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a website where I can buy a genuine Apple adapter for a lower price?

Comment: Never mind. I just order one from Apple.

Comment: Think that is your best option since there aren't many discountd on apple accessoires